# Sporadic SIGSEGV crash in OS X app

Tags: macos, crash, segmentation-fault

Any ideas as to what may be causing this sporadic crash in our OS X application?

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: EXC_I386_GPFLT

Application Specific Information:
objc_msgSend() selector name: mouseMoved:


Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff819d1097 objc_msgSend + 23
1   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff879af414 -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 1260
2   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff879502ce -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 975
3   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff877a0b89 -[NSApplication run] + 646
4   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8778b913 NSApplicationMain + 940
5   com.apple.ist.avalon.iLog       0x000000010384eab4 start + 52

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff85bd2662 kevent64 + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff844fa43d _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 239
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff844fa152 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff85bcda1a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff85bccd18 mach_msg + 64
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8545d155 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 181
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8545c779 __CFRunLoopRun + 1161
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8545c0b5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8794d16e _NSEventThread + 144
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff81ce1899 _pthread_body + 138
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff81ce172a _pthread_start + 137
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff81ce5fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff85bcda1a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff85bccd18 mach_msg + 64
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8545d155 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 181
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8545c779 __CFRunLoopRun + 1161
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8545c0b5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
5   com.apple.ist.ds.appleconnect2.ACCore   0x0000000106f36d26 -[ACCManagerWorkerThread main] + 415
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8bb1f76b __NSThread__main__ + 1318
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff81ce1899 _pthread_body + 138
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff81ce172a _pthread_start + 137
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff81ce5fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 4:: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff85bcda1a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff85bccd18 mach_msg + 64
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8545d155 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 181
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8545c779 __CFRunLoopRun + 1161
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8545c0b5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8bb1f967 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 348
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8bb1f76b __NSThread__main__ + 1318
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff81ce1899 _pthread_body + 138
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff81ce172a _pthread_start + 137
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff81ce5fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 5:: com.apple.CFSocket.private
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff85bd19aa __select + 10
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff854a8b83 __CFSocketManager + 867
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff81ce1899 _pthread_body + 138
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff81ce172a _pthread_start + 137
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff81ce5fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 6:: JavaScriptCore::BlockFree
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff85bd1716 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff81ce3c3b _pthread_cond_wait + 727
2   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff83976e16 WTF::ThreadCondition::timedWait(WTF::Mutex&, double) + 118
3   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff83976935 JSC::BlockAllocator::blockFreeingThreadMain() + 117
4   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff8396bc5f WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 15
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff81ce1899 _pthread_body + 138
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff81ce172a _pthread_start + 137
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff81ce5fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 7:: JavaScriptCore::Marking
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff85bd1716 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff81ce3c3b _pthread_cond_wait + 727
2   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff83977437 JSC::GCThread::waitForNextPhase() + 119
3   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff839772c8 JSC::GCThread::gcThreadMain() + 88
4   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff8396bc5f WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 15
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff81ce1899 _pthread_body + 138
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff81ce172a _pthread_start + 137
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff81ce5fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 8:: JavaScriptCore::Marking
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff85bd1716 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff81ce3c3b _pthread_cond_wait + 727
2   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff83977437 JSC::GCThread::waitForNextPhase() + 119
3   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff839772c8 JSC::GCThread::gcThreadMain() + 88
4   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff8396bc5f WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 15
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff81ce1899 _pthread_body + 138
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff81ce172a _pthread_start + 137
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff81ce5fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 9:: JavaScriptCore::Marking
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff85bd1716 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff81ce3c3b _pthread_cond_wait + 727
2   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff83977437 JSC::GCThread::waitForNextPhase() + 119
3   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff839772c8 JSC::GCThread::gcThreadMain() + 88
4   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff8396bc5f WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 15
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff81ce1899 _pthread_body + 138
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff81ce172a _pthread_start + 137
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff81ce5fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 10:: WebCore: LocalStorage
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff85bd1716 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff81ce3c3b _pthread_cond_wait + 727
2   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff83976ddd WTF::ThreadCondition::timedWait(WTF::Mutex&, double) + 61
3   com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff8b4276a8 WTF::PassOwnPtr<WTF::Function<void ()> > WTF::MessageQueue<WTF::Function<void ()> >::waitForMessageFilteredWithTimeout<bool (WTF::Function<void ()>*)>(WTF::MessageQueueWaitResult&, bool (&)(WTF::Function<void ()>*), double) + 168
4   com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff8b426d73 WebCore::StorageThread::threadEntryPoint() + 179
5   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff8396bc5f WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 15
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff81ce1899 _pthread_body + 138
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff81ce172a _pthread_start + 137
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff81ce5fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff85bd1e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff81ce2f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff81ce5fb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 12:: Dispatch queue: NSPersistentUI I/O
0   libz.1.dylib                    0x00007fff8c2a7587 0x7fff8c29e000 + 38279
1   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff880dfdf2 -[NSPersistentUIWindowSnapshotter writeWindowSnapshot:length:width:height:bytesPerRow:toFile:inDirectory:encryptingWithKey:uuid:checksum:isUserWaitingImpatientlyForThisThingToFinish:] + 95
2   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff879d9a77 __100-[NSPersistentUIWindowSnapshotter captureAndWriteSnapshotForWindowNumber:forWindowID:waitUntilDone:]_block_invoke92 + 231
3   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff880e13d5 run_cocoa_block + 41
4   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff880e1390 my_io_execute_passive_block + 49
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff880e1351 my_io_execute_passive_block_with_release + 14
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff844f82ad _dispatch_client_callout + 8
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff844fa68f _dispatch_queue_drain + 451
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff844fb9dd _dispatch_queue_invoke + 110
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff844f9fa3 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 75
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff844fb193 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 40
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff81ce2ef8 _pthread_wqthread + 314
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff81ce5fb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff85bd1e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff81ce2f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff81ce5fb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff85bd1e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff81ce2f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff81ce5fb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff85bd1e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff81ce2f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff81ce5fb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 16:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff85bd1e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff81ce2f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff81ce5fb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000000000168  rcx: 0x0000000000000013  rdx: 0x0000610000139960
  rdi: 0x0000618000368ac0  rsi: 0x00007fff88235ee1  rbp: 0x00007fff5c3b29b0  rsp: 0x00007fff5c3b2768
   r8: 0x0000000000000040   r9: 0x00007fff5c3b2800  r10: 0x00007fff88235ee1  r11: 0xbadd3659995fbead
  r12: 0x0000000000000000  r13: 0x00006080001f9200  r14: 0x0000000000000190  r15: 0x0000618000368ac0
  rip: 0x00007fff819d1097  rfl: 0x0000000000010246  cr2: 0x000000012b5c6000

Logical CPU:     2
Error Code:      0x00000000
Trap Number:     13
```

Comment: Looks like you are running some code on the main thread. What are you doing exactly?

Comment: Unfortunately we don't know what action the user was performing at the time of this crash. I've added more crash info however.

Answer (score 0):

Port/firewall. Block? Are you physically at the machine or is this distance logging?

Onyx/Little snitch is the first thing I think - but I don't know what's going on there...